# Send email template codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have code of codeigniter framework.

I want send email template after "if condition" but it doesn't work for me:

```
if ($this->input->post('status') == 1){

    $email_template = $this->emailtemplate_model->get_email_template(28);       

    $str_1 = str_replace($placeholders, $vals_1, $rawstring);

    $this -> email -> from($this->settings->site_email, $this->settings->site_name);
    $this->email->to(
        array($user['email'], $users['email'])
    );
    //$this -> email -> to($user['email']);
    $this -> email -> subject($email_template['title']);

    $this -> email -> message($str_1);

    $this->email->send();

}
```

Comment: So is the email sent out when the code is outside the if loop?

Comment: I want to send the message in the case of the condition

Comment: yeah. i mean have u tested the email codes outside the loop to check if the email codes is working? if it is not working then your email codes is having issue instead of the if loop